# Is there a good question to close as duplicate of double escape problem when working with RegExp constructor in JavaScript?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, canonical

I'm looking for a good duplicate closure target for these questions:

- [Regular expression in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276148/regular-expression-in-javascript/)
- [Why do I have to add double backslash on javascript regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442170/why-do-i-have-to-add-double-backslash-on-javascript-regex)
- [Javascript + Regex = Nothing to repeat error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288181/javascript-regex-nothing-to-repeat-error)
- [Range out of order in character class in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727884/range-out-of-order-in-character-class-in-javascript)
- [JavaScript RegExp Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493766/javascript-regexp-differences)
- [JavaScript regex literal vs RegExp object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400854/javascript-regex-literal-vs-regexp-object)
- [Javascript RegExp different results from constructor and literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412173/javascript-regexp-different-results-from-constructor-and-literal)
- [JavaScript and regular expressions: literal syntax Vs. RegExp object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014806/javascript-and-regular-expressions-literal-syntax-vs-regexp-object)
- [Why does this regular expression evaluate to false in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891576/why-does-this-regular-expression-evaluate-to-false-in-javascript)

Basically, the problem with constructing a RegExp by calling RegExp constructor, but forgetting to double up the backslashes. Solution is to double up the backslashes, or just use RegExp literal (if applicable).

Ideally, the answer should cover how to do it in both ways, explain why doubling up the backslashes (with examples covering several constructs in RegExp), and advise which to use in which cases.

Some candidates I currently have:

- [Building regexp from JS variables not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802601/building-regexp-from-js-variables-not-working)
- [Differences between Javascript regexp literal and constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964916/differences-between-javascript-regexp-literal-and-constructor)

Comment: If you can come up with a reasonable example yourself, you could try to answer your own canonical.  Perhaps others could give you feedback on what to include, or you could draft a sort of community wiki Q&A here and then post it on the main site.

Comment: Oh, I really would like a canonical target for that.

Comment: I like [*Shouldn't this RegExp work?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11801898/1048572) for its descriptive title :-) Apart from that, [here's another list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1048572+%5Bregex%5D+escape+backslash) of questions that probably should get closed…

Comment: Interesting that this question exists, since I was about to ask a similar question about regualr expression in R where exactly the same issue plagues the "ordinary" regular expression resources. They don't handle the special or specific cases where a language also use the backslash to escape control characters. Makes me wonder if there's a canonical list of languages that have need of `<esc><esc>`